# Grunt - Jade files with same start compile into single file

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-jade

I am using `grunt-contrib-jade` to compile my jade files. The issue I'm having is that say for example I have the following files:

```
/views/user.html
/views/user.index.hmtl
/views/user.show.html
```

These will all be compiled and merged into:

```
/views/user.html
```

Why is this happening? I want them to be in separate files like:

```
/views/user.html
/views/user.index.html
/views/user.show.html
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

This is my config:

```
jade: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      pretty: true,
      data: {
        debug: false
      }
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
      src: [
        '{app,components}/**/*.jade'
      ],
      dest: '.tmp',
      ext: '.html'
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `rename` instead of `ext`.

This should works:

```
jade: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      pretty: true,
      data: {
        debug: false
      }
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
      src: [
        '{app,components}/**/*.jade'
      ],
      dest: '.tmp',
      rename  : function (dest, src) {
        var folder    = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('/'));
        var filename  = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/'), src.length);

        filename  = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));

        return dest + folder + filename + '.min.js';
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm a little disappointed that you have to do this manually but this works. A change I needed was to put a `'/'` in between `dest` and `folder`.